# Remove noexec from Home folder

Tags: centos, permissions, fstab

I trying to deploy an rails application into `/home/app/myapp`, but when application tries to connect to Mysql, I get this error:

```
** [out :: 192.168.110.50] /home/app/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted - /home/app/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
```

'app' user has root privilegies, so it no make sense.

After googling, I find that `noexec` in home folder can block system calls. 
This my fstab file:

```
$cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Oct 17 16:48:10 2012
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/VG00-LVbarra /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=3d5ccda7-932f-4b48-a010-9ddcb99873c0 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VG00-LVhome /home                   ext4    defaults,noexec,nosuid        1 2
/dev/mapper/VG00-LVtmp  /tmp                    ext4    defaults,noexec,nosuid        1 2
/dev/mapper/VG00-LVusr  /usr                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VG00-LVvar  /var                    ext4    defaults,noexec,nosuid        1 2
```

How to remove noexec flag from home folder?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like mprotect failed, but anyway, to remove the noexec flag, change

`/dev/mapper/VG00-LVhome /home                   ext4    defaults,noexec,nosuid`

To

`/dev/mapper/VG00-LVhome /home                   ext4    defaults,nosuid`

And remount /home with `mount -o remount /home`